# Problems Re-Signing APK for Robotium testing

Tags: android, apk, signing

I am trying to resign an APK file with default debug key but I am encountering errors. I am using following piece of code. The problem is that the cmd doesn't show any error for below code but I get an error when installing the APK on android device.

```
jarsigner -keystore C:\Users\Parmar\.android\debug.keystore -storepass 

 android -keypass
 android C:\Users\Parmar\Desktop\appname.apk androiddebugkey

 zipalign 4 appname.apk TempApplicationToTest.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using java SDK greater than 1.7, so please try this code

```
jarsigner -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 applicationName.apk androiddebugkey
```

Try steps bellow to re-sign APK:
1. Rename .APK to .Zip.
2. Open by Zip tool and delete META-INF folder. (Open - do not extract)
3. Rename .zip back to .apk.
4. Re-sign APK.
5. Zip align by zip align tool (Download from internet - do not use Zip align in Android SDK)